# Node Custom error handler middleware optimization?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, custom-error-handling

Hej,

I am working on an enabler within a **nodeJS** platform which expose a **REST API**. 
I need to implement some **custom errors handlers** whose will implement some business logic.

Basically, I have to deal with a **POST request** whose content is encoded as `application/json`. 
I expect to receive a list of **objects** representing a **services** within an array.
 Each item of the array is an object which does have the following structure

```
{
  "code": "sampleCode",
  "id": "someId",
  "status: "someStatus"
}
```

In term of business logic, each service belongs to a family. And each family does have some configurations stored in a **properties file**.

Once I received the request I need to check the body content and apply some custom rules which will throw custom errors.

Rules are :

- `"code` value can't be empty.
- `"code"` value must be in a list defined in the properties
- `"code"` if code value belongs to family foo or bar id can't be empty

I implemented some small unit functions using lodash to do tests in collections.

My main regards is that do I need to go async for those process ? For now I am just calling the functions as it. As i am quite new to nodeJs and especially in terms of best practice in corporate environement I would like to have opinions from more experienced users ?

Do custom errors handlers implementing business logic should be async or there's no benefits ?

Comment: Usually, it is a good idea to go full async in node.js. It is better to have to "resynchronify" if needed, than risk to block the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs is fundamentally asynchronous, so in general, you don't do sync stuff.

If you use expressjs or similar, you should create a kind of "filter" before the request, something like :

```
function validator(req, res, next){
    //my validation code
    next();
}

app.get('/my/endpoint', validator, function (req, res) {
  req.send();
});
```

Comment: I get the idea, seems fair, it's a bit complex to implement in my use case as the application is part of a big ecosystem. It does use express but under the hood as routes as generated from a swagger yaml file. I think i need to go deeper into analysing those modules to really understand what's going on and use the proper handler

Comment: express is based on the concept of middleware http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router if you can access a route, you may just have to put an extra function, call next, and voila. Definitely go a little deeper, as it seems to be a custom configuration.